# Windows Phone 8 , call a function when the user clicks on Dismiss when an Alarm goes off

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have created an instance alarm class with following properties:

```
Alarm k = new Alarm("lop")
            {
                Content = "Hey Office Time",
                BeginTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(0.3),
                RecurrenceType = RecurrenceInterval.Daily,
                ExpirationTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(30),

            };
```

The goes off at the time specified, but when the user clicks on "Dismiss" or "Snooze" button i want to do some work, then i want decide whether i want to turn off or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible wit the current SDK.